# What is the right econometric model to use

Tags: regression, panel-data, difference-in-difference, causalimpact

I want to evaluate how the cultivation of a particular crop has impacted several socioeconomic variables at the municipality level. I have a map that identifies the municipalities where this crop can be grown (due to climate, etc. they are all located in the same area) and data for the last 15 years of where the crop has actually been cultivated.
My idea was to use a Dif-in-Dif model to compare how these socioeconomic variables have evolved over time, comparing the municipalities where the crop is grown vs municipalities where it isn't grown but would be possible to do it.
Is this the right approach?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome. How will you be measuring crop yield? Also, are you assessing some sort of policy that increased/decreased production in some municipalities but not others? Could you provide more clarification?

Comment: The crop yield is reported yearly by the goverment in tons per hec by municipality. There were some policies meant to increase the cultivation but were open to everyone not to some municipalities exclusively